# Having trouble defining two matrix multiplication methods

Tags: c++, matrix-multiplication

I'm struggling to define a standard multiplication method and a threaded one.

First, I can't seem to get the standard method correct. I want it to just fill another empty matrix with the product of two matrices, and I believe I've written it correctly, but I keep getting errors upon errors.

Here is all the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <future>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void matrixMultiply(double** a, double** b, double** product, int size) {

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
       for (int j = 0; j < size; j++) {
          for (int k = 0; k < size; k++) {
          product[i][j] += a[i][k] * b[k][j];
          }
       }
    }


}

void matrixMultiplyThreaded(double a, double b, double product, int dimLower, int dimUpper, int dim) {
    for (int i = dimLower; i < dimUpper; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < dim; j++) {
            for (int k = 0; k < dim; k++) {
                product[i][j] += a[i][k] * b[k][j];
            }
        }
    }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    if (argv < 3) {
       cout << "Not enough arguments.";
    }
    int numTimes = atoi(argv[1]);

    int size = atoi(argv[3]);
    double a[size][size], b[size][size];
    double product[size][size] = {};

    for (int i=0; i<size; i++) {
       for (int j=0; j < size; j++) {
          a[i][j] = 2;
          b[i][j] = 3;
       }
    }
    double t1 = get_wallTime();
    if (argv[2] = "yes") {
       int dim1 = size / 2;
       for (int n = 0; n < numTimes; n++) {
          auto thread1 = std::async(matrixMultiplyThreaded, a, b, product, 0, dim1, size);

          auto thread2 = std::async(matrixMultiplyThreaded, a, b, product, dim1, size, size);

    } }
    else { 
       for (int m = 0; m < numTimes; m++) {

          matrixMultiply(a[size][size],b[size][size], product[size][size], size);
    } }
    double t2 = get_wallTime();
    double totalTime = t2 - t1;
    cout << "time : " << totalTime;


}
```

I'm measuring the difference in runtimes between a threaded version and the standard version. However, I'm new to C++, coming from C/Java, and I'm getting tripped up on the differences in syntac. If anyone could shed some light on this I'd be very grateful.

Here are some error messages I'm getting:

```
multiplyMatrix.cpp: In function 'void matrixMultiplyThreaded(double, double, double, int, int, int)':
multiplyMatrix.cpp:37:26: error: invalid types 'double[int]' for array subscript
                 product[i][j] += a[i][k] * b[k][j];
                          ^
multiplyMatrix.cpp:37:37: error: invalid types 'double[int]' for array subscript
                 product[i][j] += a[i][k] * b[k][j];
                                     ^
multiplyMatrix.cpp:37:47: error: invalid types 'double[int]' for array subscript
                 product[i][j] += a[i][k] * b[k][j];
                                               ^
multiplyMatrix.cpp: In function 'int main(int, char**)':
```

Comment: Maybe look at how `matrixMultiply` is defined and compare it to `matrixMultiplyThreaded`? The `*` is important.

Comment: The proto of `matrixMultiplyThreaded` is also wrong. There's a difference between a 2d array and an array of pointers to 1d arrays. Study your C++ book!

Comment: Hmm you're right, you know I forgot to even check which function the error message was referring to, not realizing that I had fixed the first one with `**`. Another question though, I get the error ` error: ISO C++ forbids comparison between pointer and integer [-fpermissive]` for checking if `argv < 3`. Any quick ideas on that?

Comment: `argv` is your char* array. Use `argc`, your number of args: `if(argc < 3){}`

Comment: Using variable-length arrays with user-input size can be dangerous as they may overflow the stack.